# How to show content of unapplied Mercurial queue patch?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

From the `hg` command line interface, is there a way to show the content of an unapplied Mercurial queue patch without having to apply it or having to find the patch file manually in the corresponding queue patch folder from the `.hg`directory?

Answer (score 0):

No, not quite. Unapplied patches from an mq are exactly not part of the repository itself, thus not accessible by the normal mercurial commands.

The (experimental) evolve extension is meant to become the successor of the mq extension. Making use of mercurial's phases, it allows to alter patches and easily evolve (similar to rebase) changesets which are children of the changed changeset. There all changesets, whatever phase, are accessible by all the usual mercurial commands.